# How to properly parametrize a SECP256K1 curve using the SE051 IoT SDK?

Tags: iot, smartcard, elliptic-curve, secp256k1

in order to use an elliptic curve such as the SECP256K1 curve (used by Bitcoin or Ethereum) in a SE051 IoT secure element(NXP) , it is required to firstly create that curve and to parametrize it using the function `SetECCurveParam`

NXP documentation doesn't say much about the parametrization in itself, only that all the parameters from the curve must be set one after the others (apparently without a precise order) and once the last parameter is received, the card will return the final status: Ok (0x9000) if all the parameters are valid, or an error message otherwise (something else than 0x9000)

The five parameters are defined as such:

```
CURVE_PARAM_A 0x01

CURVE_PARAM_B 0x02

CURVE_PARAM_G 0x04

CURVE_PARAM_N 0x08

CURVE_PARAM_PRIME 0x10
```

This should be explicit enough:
A is the 'A' parameter in the reduced Weierstrass form of the curve (y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B)
B is the 'B' parameter in the reduced Weierstrass form of the curve (y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B)
G is the base point of the curve
N is the order of the base point
PRIME is the order of F_p on which the curve is based

I end with this

```c
byte PRIME[]={ 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0x2F};

byte A[] ={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

byte B[] ={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07};

//uncompressed
byte G[]={0x04 ,0x79,0xBE,0x66,0x7E ,0xF9,0xDC,0xBB,0xAC ,0x55,0xA0,0x62,0x95 ,0xCE,0x87,0x0B,0x07 ,0x02,0x9B,0xFC,0xDB ,0x2D,0xCE,0x28,0xD9 ,0x59,0xF2,0x81,0x5B ,0x16,0xF8,0x17,0x98 ,0x48,0x3A,0xDA,0x77 ,0x26,0xA3,0xC4,0x65 ,0x5D,0xA4,0xFB,0xFC ,0x0E,0x11,0x08,0xA8 ,0xFD,0x17,0xB4,0x48 ,0xA6,0x85,0x54,0x19 ,0x9C,0x47,0xD0,0x8F ,0xFB,0x10,0xD4,0xB8};
//compressed
//byte G[]={0x02 ,0x79,0xBE,0x66,0x7E ,0xF9,0xDC,0xBB,0xAC ,0x55,0xA0,0x62,0x95 ,0xCE,0x87,0x0B,0x07 ,0x02,0x9B,0xFC,0xDB ,0x2D,0xCE,0x28,0xD9 ,0x59,0xF2,0x81,0x5B ,0x16,0xF8,0x17,0x98};

byte n[] = {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE ,0xBA,0xAE,0xDC,0xE6 ,0xAF,0x48,0xA0,0x3B ,0xBFD,0x25,0xE8,0xC ,0xD0,0x36,0x41,0x41};
```

for these values (G compressed or uncompressed) I receive '0x6985' after the last parameter, indicating something is wrong. However, the parameters for SECP256K1 are well-known and after checking again and again I cannot see the reason for the error. It is also not an endianness issue.

Does someone have experienced a similar issue  with the SE051 and what can be wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There was a typo in the byte array for N...